# Inheriting bucketable template

Tags: templates, buckets

The plan is my bucket to have different templates that need to be bucketable let's say 10 templates, Can I just create a 1 bucketable template and inherit it for the other 10 templates so they can be also bucketable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Bucketable template that you can then set as a base template for any templates that you want to be bucketable as well.  I used to do this in the past.  In fact, I would have a base bucketable template and base bucket template that I would assign to templates so they would have those characteristics.

The Base bucket on the standard values, you could set the field __Is Bucket to true.

Then on the Base bucketable, update the standard values item to set __Bucketable to true.

Then just assign this base template to those 10 templates as a base template.  Whenever you create a new item based on any of those ten base templates, it should be bucketable based on the inherited base template of that template.